# Commit changements from jHipster container to JHipster docker image is not working

Tags: docker, jhipster

I downloaded a jHipster docker image from DockerHub.
I run ./mvnw and everything works.
I wanted to save this changes by commiting to a new docker image by :

```
docker commit CONTAINER_ID NEW-IMAGE-NAME
```

When I run :

```
docker container run --name jhipster  -p 8080:8080 -p 9000:9000 -p 3001:3001 -d -t NEW-IMAGE-NAME
```

It works but the changements that I made does not exist and

> /home/jhipster/app
>     is empty.

The name of original image is **jhipster/jhispter**, and the created one is named **jhipster-image-template**.
The size of the new one has increased, that means files are added.

[image]

How should I do to save the modification in a template docker image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by binding volume.
I should use -v flag when running the docker image.

```
docker container run --name CONTAINER-NAME -v ~/FOLDER_NAME_TO_BIND:/home/jhipster/app -v ~/.m2:/home/jhipster/.m2 -p 8080:8080 -p 9000:9000 -p 3001:3001 -d -t IMAGE_NAME
```

and there is no need to commit to a new docker image because the current container will save modification